# Get back to the top of switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, break

A question about a switch statement. Instead of adding the typical `break;` statement, I would like to to back to the top of the switch statement again.   Like this:

```
switch(mainmenu)
{

case "2":
break;

case "3":
break;

case "4":
break;

 }
```

After reading case 2, I would to exit out of the switch statement.  How do I do that?

Comment: Can you post the full code? I think there would be a better way to solve your problem- going back to the top of a switch statement would give a high chance of creating an infinite loop...

Comment: Just call the function containing the `switch` again after changing whatever you need to to make `mainmenu` have a different value.

Comment: Why do you want to go back to the top of the `switch` statement? What's wrong with `break;`? And please paste the whole code that is involved in this scenario.

Comment: use recursion.  it's hard to give you an example when you don't show any other code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to achieve that, here's an example, you will need to adapt it as I don't have the whole code.

The following is a simple example, it can obviously be adapted and improved related to your requirements.

```js
function generateMenu(data, result = []) {
  if (data.length === 0) {
    return result;
  }
  
  switch(data[0]) {
    case "1":
    result.push('data-1');
    break;
    case "2":
    result.push('data-2');
    break;
    case "3":
    result.push('data-3');
    break;
  }
  
  data.splice(0, 1);
  
  return generateMenu(data, result);
}

console.log(generateMenu(['2', '3']));
```